# angularJS: window.alert only after method is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller with the help of service i'm sending some qr-data to users so:

```
    $scope.sendtoList = function () {
        $scope.qrStatus = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function (item) {        
          if (item.Selected){
            inviteService.sendQR(item.Emails.main, $scope.company.Id).then(function(response) {
              $scope.qrStatus = true;              
            },
            function(err) {
              $scope.qrStatus = false;              
            });
          }
        });
        if ($scope.qrStatus){
          $window.alert('QR-code has been sended successfully.');
        }
        else{
          $window.alert('Warning! QR-code has not been sended successfully.');
        }
      }
```

and i see some strange behaviour: it always show warning alert, even if method is done succesfully - i think it is of promisses. But how could i show window in my case only after servise promisse is returned?

Comment: You need to treat this in a non-blocking manner, rather than a blocking manner. Your promises are returning way after your code has completed.

Comment: @BrianNoah could you provide code example?

Comment: done. Not tested, but something around what I posted should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this with promises, you need to create a counter that checks every time a user is updated, and then triggers the alert once all are accounted for.

```
$scope.sendQRtoList = function () {
    $scope.qrStatus = false;
    var count = 0;
    var length = $scope.users.length;
    var error = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function (item) {
        if (item.Selected){
            inviteService
                .sendQR(item.Emails.main, $scope.company.Id)
                .then(function(response) {
                    //yay!  
                },
                function(err) {
                    error++;
                })
                .finally(function () {
                    count++;
                    if (count === length && error === 0) {
                        $window.alert('QR-code has been sent successfully.');
                    }
                    if (count === length && error !== 0) {
                        $window.alert('Warning! QR-code has not been sent successfully.')
                    }
                });
        }
    });
};
```

`.finally()` happens on every promise, that's where you want to add your counter incrementation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope one of the following helps

1) Try looking at the following post: [$success call back function from AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811655/success-call-back-function-from-angular-js)

Its a similar question and the following js fiddle might help: http://jsfiddle.net/E5HGy/6/

2) A counter as stated above would also solve the problem, something such as

```
if(i == selector.length) 
    // "callback"
```

would essientially solve it