# I cant return the value of variable that has the data angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck here. what's wrong with my code? i can't get the value of the variable when I  return it.

```
accountManagers : function( id ) {

        var accountManager;

        $http.get( URL + 'server/agents_account_managers.php?id=' + id ).success( function ( data ) {

            if ( data != 0 ) {

                accountManager = data[0].first_name + ' ' + data[0].last_name ;

            }

        });     

        return accountManager;


    }
```

thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply, i checked the link and found there's a lot of explanation. i am having a hard time to understand it all. could you please give me a summary or simplified solution to this? thanks

Comment: Please refer this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811655/success-call-back-function-from-angularjs

Comment: thanks for the link, my question is my function is in the service. will $q work in service? thanks again

Comment: i already tried it, but it showed me this : d {$$state: Object}

Answer (score 0):

Try using `then()`.

```
$http.get('/yoururl').then(
  function(response) { // successCallback
    console.log('success: ' + response);
  }, function (error) {  // errorcallback
    console.log('error: ' + error);
  });
```

This uses Angular's `$http` shortcut methods, and will handle any errors in the `errorcallback` method. 

You should also avoid using `.success` and `.error` when using [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

Comment: can you please check what's wrong with this...

Comment: var crmGlobalServices = angular.module( 'crmGlobalServices', [] );

crmGlobalServices.factory( 'crmGlobalServices', function( $http, $q ) {

 var accountManager;


 function agentsAccountManager( id ) {

  $http.get( URL + 'server/agents_account_managers.php?id=' + id ).then( function ( response ) {

   console.log( response.data[0].first_name ); // already success

   accountManager = response.data[0].first_name + ' ' + response.data[0].last_name;

  },

  function ( error ) {

   console.log( 'error : ' + error );

  });  

  console.log( accountManager );

  return accountManager;

 } 
});

Comment: You should probably update your answer with a plunker